# How to add a third-party component into an Ext.Tabpanel?

Tags: extjs, tabs, extjs4

I've a 3rd-party component `CompFoo` to be added into an Ext.Tabpanel,

**HTML:**

```
<div id="div1">
</div>
<div id="div2">
</div>
```

and I render the CompFoo to div2, the tabpanel to div1.

```
var Foo = new MacroHard.bar.box({
 ...
 renderTo: 'div2'
});

var tabs = Ext.createWidget('tabpanel',{
renderTo: 'input-div',
layout: 'fit',
height: '80%',
activeTab: 0,
items:[
       {
           title: 'User',
           items: [
            {
                id: 'userid-txtfld',
                xtype: 'textfield',
                fieldLabel: 'User ID',
                name: 'userid',
            },
           ]
       },
  ]....
```

What I want to do is to put my CompFoo into one of the tab.

Two ways:
1) Create a div with given ID into a tab, or 2) put the CompFoo into the 'items' of the TabPanel.

I don't know how to write the code in either way.

Comment: Is the third party "component" HTML only, or is there more to it?

Comment: I could render the component into a given div, so you can take it as pure HTML

Answer (score 0, accepted):

put into your `items:{}`

`new Ext.Panel({id: 'someID',title:'someTitle',hmtl:'<your html>',...})`

didn't test but should work

another way wich i'd prefer is using `loader:{url:<url to the site you want to show>,renderer:'frame',...}` instead of `html` in the panel

Comment: I think that goes with the second approach mentioned in my question.